# How can I download a file from a subfolder in a amazon s3bucket using php?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have vendor folder in my local.

I want to **download** a file from a sub folder which is inside my **bucket's** folder, to my computer's **directory** with the same name.

Let's say there is a bucket name **"ABC"** a folder is there inside it, is **"DEF"** And there is a sub folder named **"XYZ"** in **"DEF"**. In which the files are present in folder **"XYZ"**.

So, anyone can help me in resolving this?

```
function downloadFromS3($s3version,$s3region,$s3accesskey,$s3secret,$bucket,$directory){
        $s3 = new S3Client([
            'version' => $s3version,
            'region'  => $s3region,
            'credentials' =>
            array(
                'key'=>$s3accesskey,
                'secret'  =>$s3secret
            )
        ]);

        try {
            $basePath = 'downloads/';

            $s3->downloadBucket($basePath . $directory, $bucket, $directory);
        }
       catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
        }
    }
```

I am getting error like

```
 Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\Performance\TestManagement\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: In License, it is given that version 2.0 @Jamie_D

Comment: I strongly suggest [upgrading to Version 3 of the Amazon PHP SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_migration.html) and then follow the client configuration instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html). Ater that you can use the [downloadBucket method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#creating-a-client)

Comment: Going strictly by the overall look of your client configuration however, it looks like you're using the client configuration method for version 3. If you do not want to upgrade, then you need to configure your client using the [V2 Method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html)